# PostgreSQL 9.4 database cannot be saved with pgAdmin 3 (Windows 8.1)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am working with confuence under Windows 8.1 and have produced a lot of Input there.

Now **I wanted to backup my PostgreSQL 9.4 database with pgAdmin 3**.

I get the error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.18\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "C:\Users\milenko\Desktop\output.backup" "confluence"

**pg_dump: server version: 9.4.1; pg_dump version: 9.3.1**

**pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch**

Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to tell pgAdmin to use the 9.4 binaries, through the "Binary paths" section in the options dialog:

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22.2/options-browser.html

---

your pgAdmin version is a bit old as well. 1.20 ships with Postgres 9.4, not 1.18

Comment: the link is no more valid.

Answer (score 2):

Also I found very effective to just replace pg_dump.exe in pgadmin version folder with my pg_dump.exe from my Postgres database.

I see why the solution above is better, but if someone would have problems with that, this also seems like functional alternative.

Answer (score -1):

This solution above works fine for me!. You should try. Inside pgadmin folder, change pg_dump.exe name to pg_dump-bkp.exe and copy&paste pg_dump.exe from postgres folder.